# Powershell PSCredential implementation in Golang when making a http requests

Tags: linux, powershell, go, request

In a web request initiated in powershell I am able to authorize with a website which i use this code:

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "grade" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist "student", $password
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'url to the website' -Credential $cred
```

Now I want to implement the same thing in go:

```
tr := &http.Transport{
    TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true},
    DisableKeepAlives: true,
}
client := &http.Client{
    Transport: tr,
}
v := url.Values{}
v.Set("steve", "third")
req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "the same website as above", strings.NewReader(v.Encode()))
req.SetBasicAuth("steve", "third")

resp, err := client.Do(req)
```

I can make a post request against other websites like `https://ptsv2.com/`.

My only question is what is the role of `PSCredential` and `SecureString` and how can I reimplement the same functionality in the golang?

- My deployment environment is **linux** so I cannot import Powershell
  or C# into my code
- Go version is 1.17.2
- The website is local and under development but I don't have access to the source code

Comment: `SecureString` is badly named and should probably have been called `ObscureString`. What is your motivation for trying to port these constructs to go? Can't you just... not?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I am changing my environment to Linux and Since my code is getting very chunky I had to consider a lot of things like portability and cross-platform.

Comment: You're definitely moving to linux and have to make concessions based on that (like not running powershell and c#), but you're also striving for cross-platform portability? Which is it? :) In any case, porting `PSCredential` and `SecureString` types to go won't give you any functionality - they're just specialized data containers. A `SecureString` is a container of `char`'s (the characters that make up a password for example), a `PSCredential` is just a container for a user identity and a `SecureString`. The thing you need to solve is how to pick an authentication scheme :)